# router.post is not rendering a page

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am learning node. I am stuck where I can render a view from get method but not from post.

app.js

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var favicon = require("serve-favicon");
var logger = require("morgan");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var test = require("./routes/test");

app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(test);
```

test.js

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
router.get("/test", function(req, res, next) {

  res.render("testView1");  //working OK

});

router.post("/test", function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("Its a test") // Working OK
  res.render("testView2",{

      // some data to be posted

  }); // not redirecting to testView2
});

module.exports = router;
```

post /test is to be called on a button click event. it should render testView2 page where I have to display some data. I am stuck with this rendering kind of thing......Please help me to learn this.

Thanks,

Sunil

testView2.ejs is just a simple plain html template as of now
testView2.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>testview 2</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

testView1.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title></title>
    <% include ./scriptLinks/headerLinks.ejs %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>TestView 1</h1>
    <button id="btn-test">Test</button>
    <script>
      $("#btn-test").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post("/test", { name: " some data" });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and yes All ejs files are in view folder.
Thank you.

Comment: If You're saying `Working OK` in comments and You've issues on view level so - add ejs files to Your question and also tell us what kind of data You're passing to Your  `testView2` ?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title></title>
  
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>testview 2</h1>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: this is just a simple html file

Comment: 1) add Your `simple html file` to Your question. 2) Your simple html file must have `.ejs` extension and must be placed inside `views` folder

Comment: now seems correct. but add `testView1.ejs` also, since we have to know how You call `post /test` from first view

Comment: post /test is called through a jquery on click event, as you can see in testView1.ejs file. I also tried it by ajax call but result is again the same.

Comment: I've already answered, check one of solutions. It's not nodejs, expressjs, ejs issue. it's lack of frontend experience...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it will not work. `$.post` is ajax request + it's asynchronous so it will not make browser navigate to `/test` route with `post` method in header.

Make `testView1.ejs` have such content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title></title>
    <% include ./scriptLinks/headerLinks.ejs %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>TestView 1</h1>
    <form method="post" action="/test">
      <button id="btn-test">Test</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

but if You insist on ajax call - so do this:

1) `testView2.ejs` must consist of only this (no headers, no body, no html tags):

```
<h1>testview 2</h1>
```

2) `testView1.ejs` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title></title>
    <% include ./scriptLinks/headerLinks.ejs %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>TestView 1</h1>
    <form method="post" action="/test">
      <button id="btn-test">Test</button>
    </form>

    <script>
      $(function() {

        $("from").on('submit', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();

          var method = $[$(this).attr('method').toLowerCase()];
          if (!method) method = 'get';

          method(
            $(this).attr('action'), 
            { name: " some data" }, 
            function(response) {
              $('body').html(response);
            });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**warning:** I don't recommend to inject html response to body - it may lead to unexpected behavior, since You don't seem to have enough frontend experience

Comment: Thank you very much. it already cost me one night and a day, you save another one. by the way I find your 1st suggestion useful at my level. Thank you once again.